# How to rewrite jQuery's trigger() in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

What is the best way to rewrite jQuery's `trigger()` in React?

I need to trigger an element when a component failed to mount.

```
$(document).trigger('timer');
```

How can this be reproduced in React?

```
componentDidMount(){
  $(document).trigger('timer');
}
```

`trigger()` doesn't work.

Comment: Read about flux or redux :)

Comment: http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use state to tell the component when to mount; I am assuming that you can build a timer that begins when mounted.

```
import Loading from...;
import React from 'react';

export default class Timer extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timer: false
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
                this.setState({ timer: true })
            }
    render() {

        return({ this.state.timer ? <Timer /> : <Loading/> });
    }
}
```